# Extending custom config array in Codeigniter within a view file

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

I'am using a codeigniter 2.x. What i need is to insert a values into an array of `config/template.php` from inside of a view file `/views/home.php`.

I've created a custom config file `application/config/template.php`:

```
$config['site_name'] = "Sitename";
$config['site_lang'] = "En-en";
$config['page_name'] = "Pagename";
$config['css_page'] = "default";
$config['alias'] = "";

$config['head_meta'] = array(
    'description' => 'description',
    'keywords' => 'meta, keywords',
    'stylesheets' => array(
        'template.css'
    ),
    'scripts' => array(
        'jquery.js',
        'template.js'
    ),
    'charset' => 'UTF-8'
);
$config['sidebars'] = array();
```

Then, i use `application/views/template/template.php` as my main HTML layout, where at the beginning I include a file `application/views/template/includes/inc-tpl-cfg.php` which globalize my configurations for a template into an one file with arrays, so i could access them a little bit easier. Here is the content of that `inc-tpl-cfg.php`:

```
<?php

// No direct acces to this file
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* Template configuration needs to be defined to make them accessible in the whole template */
$cfg_template = array(
    'sitename'      => $this->config->item('site_name'),
    'sitelang'      => $this->config->item('site_lang'),
    'pagename'      => $this->config->item('page_name'),
    'csspage'       => $this->config->item('css_page'),
    'charset'       => $this->config->item('charset','head_meta'),
    'description'   => $this->config->item('description','head_meta'),
    'keywords'      => $this->config->item('keywords','head_meta'),
    'stylesheets'   => $this->config->item('stylesheets','head_meta'),
    'scripts'       => $this->config->item('scripts','head_meta'),
    'sidebars'      => $this->config->item('sidebars')
);

/* Template variables */
$cfg_assetsUrl = base_url() . 'assets';

// If pagename exists than concatenate it with a sitename, else output only sitename
if(!empty($cfg_template['pagename'])){
    $title = $cfg_template['pagename'] . ' - ' . $cfg_template['sitename'];
}else{
    $title = $cfg_template['sitename'];
}
```

And one part in my main template layout is block with sidebars:

```
<div id="tpl-sidebar">
  <?php foreach($cfg_template['sidebars'] as $sidebar):?>
    <?php $this->load->view('modules/'. $sidebar);?>
  <?php endforeach ;?>
</div>
```

And at last, it loads a `application/views/home.php` into the specific `div` block inside `applications/views/template/template.php`. This is a `/views/home.php`:

```
<?php

// No direct acces to this file
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// Page configuration
$this->config->set_item('page_name','Homepage');
$this->config->set_item('css_page','home');
$this->config->set_item('alias','home');

?>

    <p>
        WELCOME BLABLABLA
    </p>
</h3>
```

There is a section where i can define/overwrite a default values from `config/template.php` and use a specific ones for each views. So my questions is, how can i extend a `$config[sidebar]` array inside this view file by inserting some new items, for exemple: `recent.php`,`rss.php` etc... ?

Sorry for a big code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you believe that this is possible? Just for poking around or did you actually do some research?

Comment: @hakra sorry for dumb questions, but i'am really confused with this one, i've googled for something like `php array insert values` etc... but just can't get it. You think it's impossible ? Or just pointing me at the right direction so i could continue to search for some clues ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it:

this is what i should insert inside of a `views/home.php`:

```
$this->config->set_item('sidebars',array(
  'recent',
  'rss'
));
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set config variables in controller?
 Views are not meant for logics.

Comment: i want to have it in a view files where i can define all of common things such as "page_name", h1 title, alias,etc... in one place, They are not dynamic, but defined by me. You think it's not a best practice, right ?

Comment: This is definitely not the best practice. The best practice would be to define those variables in controller. MVC approach is meant to distinguish logic from view, but you are trying to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that in the views, setting that data should be done from the controllers.
The views should only handle view logic, not setting the logic itself...
Then you pass the vars from the controller, when it's all set and ready to go, into the view.